# Getting key with maximum value in dictionary for each Key value

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I have a dictionary where keys are strings, and values are integers.

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'ent': 123}, {'id': 2, 'ent': 123}, {'id': 3, 'ent': 456}, {'id': 4, 'ent': 456}, {'id': 5, 'ent': 123}]
```

How do I get the dictionary with the maximum value of `id` for given `ent`?

Expected Outcome:

```
[{'id': 4, 'ent': 456},{'id': 5, 'ent': 123}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
[{'id': max(list(filter(None,[v['id'] if v['ent'] == i else None for v in list1]))), 'ent':i} for i in set([i['ent'] for i in list1])]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 4, 'ent': 456}, {'id': 5, 'ent': 123}]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First filter on `'ent'`. You can use a set comprehension `{d['ent'] for d in list1}`
2. Then use `max` with a key function to find that max of that filtered list with `max([d for d in list1 if d['ent']==e], key=lambda d: d['id'])`

So:

```
for e in {d['ent'] for d in list1}:
    print(max([d for d in list1 if d['ent']==e], key=lambda d: d['id']))
```

Prints:

```
{'id': 4, 'ent': 456}
{'id': 5, 'ent': 123}
```

Which can be a list comprehension:

```
[max([d for d in list1 if d['ent']==e], key=lambda d: d['id'])
     for e in {d['ent'] for d in list1}]
```

Result:

```
[{'id': 4, 'ent': 456}, {'id': 5, 'ent': 123}]
```

You can also use a sort approach that uniquifies the list based on the sorted result:

```
list({d['ent']:d 
    for d in sorted(list1, key=lambda d: (d['id'], d['ent']))}.values())
```

That is potentially faster with large lists since it is `O(n log n)` complexity versus the `O(n * n)` of the other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
res = {}
for item in list1:
    id, ent = item['id'], item['ent']
    try:
        if id > res[ent]:
            res[ent] = id
    except KeyError:
        res[ent] = id
```